# How to fetch text from an website into the javascript

Tags: javascript

i am making a chrome extension.
i need a text from an open website in the active tab of browser to use in javascript of the extension. how to fetch it in there?

like in this website [link](https://www.utctime.net/ist-indian-time-now)
in this site i want the time fetched in the javascript.
i am 2 hours ago started new.
Please help with an example code if anyone can.

just show an example of how to store that text in a variable.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+extension+scrape+website+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the manifest it should probably be fairly basic, you might want to restrict it to a single site and link some js to run so

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "some name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "description",

    "content_scripts": [ {
        "matches": ["https://www.utctime.net/ist-indian-time-now"],
        "js": ["main.js"]
    } ]

   
}
```

and the JS is pretty much getting the specific element, here it has an id named time so that can be used.

`main.js`

```
getTime = () =>{
    time = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML
    console.log(time)
}
setInterval(getTime, 100);
```

Comment: Hey one quick follow up. How to store this time in a variable string? so to use it somewhere else in script?

Comment: and how to call one script into another? -_-

Comment: As your litterly extracting the text containing the time your getting a string (there are ":" within to). Also extentions work by having a manifest json file manage details and can link js, here you get the time as a variable, from here you can link new files in the manifest and just call functions or set variables.